# Populate Combo Box from Userform Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have two simple pieces of code in a Userform and what I want to do, I believe is quite straight forward however I'm stuck!

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wkb As Workbook

    With Me.CB_Excel_File
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            .AddItem wkb.Name
        Next wkb
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CB_Excel_File_Change()

Dim wks As Worksheet

    With Me.CB_Worksheet
        For Each wks In ***Me.CB_Excel_File.Value.Worksheets***
            .AddItem wks.Name
        Next wks
    End With

End Sub
```

Its the piece with *** that I'm stuck on as I want to list all of the worksheets in the workbook that is selected by the user from the Userform_Initialize code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the selected workbook name into the Workbooks collection as a variable, as so:

```
Private Sub CB_Excel_File_Change()

Dim wks As Worksheet

With Me.CB_Worksheet
    For Each wks In Workbooks(CB_Excel_File.Value).Worksheets
        .AddItem wks.Name
    Next wks
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jimmy! Perfect! For some reason I can't green tick this as my computer keeps saying an error has occurred when I try. Appreciate your help though!

Comment: No problem, try again later so future users who may have this problem know that it's met your needs